# nginx in docker reverseproxy configuration issue

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have make a nginx as below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr /share /nginx /html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://internalapi:8080;
    }
    location ~ /api2/[^/]+$ {
        proxy_pass http://internalapi:8080;
    }
    location /allprofiles/ {
        proxy_pass http://internalapi:8080/client/allprofiles;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri /  / index.html;
    }
}
```

For my testing, It work when I use

> http://localhost/allprofiles/

, it can return the json data
but I want to make it work on

> http://localhost/api/client/allprofiles

can I know how to make it ? Becuase I want

> http://localhost/api/{any uri or query strings}

can call different API instead of create multi location in conf

In recent, I get the link from https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-1/, and try to

** I find the reason, as because my dotnet controller

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ClientController : controllerbase
```

I need to change with

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ClientController : controllerbase
```

But if I want to keep `Route("[controller]")]`, but in ngrix still use `location /api/` , is that possible ? or need to use rewrite function ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set an explicit `location` e.g.:

```
upstream internal-api {
  server internalapi:8080 max_fails=3;
}

upstream external-api {
  server externalapi:8080 max_fails=3;
}

# default pass all api requests to the internalapi
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://internalapi;
}

# handle explicit location for externalapi traffic
location = /api/client/allprofiles/ {
  proxy_pass http://externalapi;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but my problem is 
I want to make it work on http://localhost/api/{any uri}, which any uri will pass to internal api
For example, http://localhost/api/client/allprofiles want to get same result as http://localhost/allprofiles/, even I make another http://localhost/api/query/something, I don't need to location rule in nginx.conf then can redirect to http://internalapi:8080/api/query/something